# blitz++ multidimentional arrays, declaring it's dimensions later

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, containers, blitz++

Ok, I know a way to declare a multidimentional array in blitz. You'd do it like this:

```
blitz::Array<double, 3> blitzArray( 3, 4, 5 );
```

and access elements like so:

```
blitzArray(0,0,0) = 1.0001;
```

But what if i wanted to declare the array without specifying the dimensions at the beginning.
You see, the dimensions always vary. Like the first dimension would start out as a 3, then turn into a 8 and then 2 etc. And the same goes with the other dimensions.
Now I have loops for those dimensions. My code parses a file and can feed in the dimensions.
So can I do something like:

```
blitz::Array<double, 3> blitzArray;    //declaration
//later in the program after doing stuff
f=0
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
 for(j=0;j<m;++j){
  for(k=0;k<o;++k){       //n,m,o are decided by some other constraints, doesn't matter
   blitzArray(i,j,k)=foo[f++]; //foo is a vector<double>
```

so here I'm making an array of array of arrays and feeding in every array cell with what's in the foo vector. But the dimensions keep changing.

Comment: I don't know whether the required thing is possible to implement with blitz++ but you may want to have a look at another C++ library, marray: https://github.com/bjoern-andres/marray. It features multi-dimensional arrays and views whose dimension, shape, size and indexing order (first or last coordinate major order) can be set and changed at runtime.

Comment: I'll look into that right away. But studying new material would take quite a bit of time...which i dont have. Could a 3d vector do the trick?

Comment: You mean vector of vectors of vectors? I imagine it could do the job but there would be drawbacks: first, you have to be careful with resizing of each inner vector otherwise it is very easy to access non-existing vector element with operator[] and get undefined behavior. Second, runtime resizing of each inner vector separately means multiple memory allocations which is worse for performance than one memory allocation. Don't know whether it is critical for your task or not.

Comment: bummer..not going to use vectors. Looked up documentation for mArrays. Couldn't find enough. Then came across a pdf that made everything complicated(with what looked like references to calculus and permutations etc). Now looking at boost/multi_array. That would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: You will still need to specify the dimensions when you create an instance of boost::multi_array but the good news is that "additional features, such as resizing, reshaping, and creating views are available". 

BTW, you could also try to create a map or hash with some struct consisting of three indices as a key. Therefore you would be able to actually insert elements with operator[] at runtime and also avoid additional memory loss for not really needed array elements. You can read about associative containers in C++ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers_%28C%2B%2B%29).

Comment: Thank you very much dmitry. I dont have enough reputation to upvote your comments but will as soon as i get enough. :)